# Numeric fields lose leading zero while writing CSV in c#

Tags: c#, csv

I'm using an ASP.NET application which exports my clients data to CSV, I need my clients Phone number to be with the leading Zero.
I need the phone numbers to be without "-" and without quotations, and due to the nature of my application I cannot use 3rd party products such as EPPLUS.
I've tried to put a space and let the CSV "understand" that I need the phone number as text , but that doesn't seem right.

I would like to know how to make the excel include the leading zero , without using 3rd party products.

Thanks

Comment: In one of my applications i remember prepending leading zero field with single quote. Just one, at the start of the value

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Change the data that is saved in the csv with the following format:

```
 ="00023423"
```

CSV example:

```
David,Sooo,="00023423",World
```

This will show 00023423 in excel and not 23423.

Comment: This will convert the value to a *formula*. The correct way is to prepend a single quote.

Comment: That no longer works, sadly - the quote is now displayed as part of the cell.  But any character that *can't be part of a number* will trigger non-numeric interpretation, thus preserving leading zeros.  So you can pre-pend or append a tab or non-breaking-space (`"\xA0"`) instead.  Prepending also prevents interpretation of the field as a formula if it begins with +,-,=,@ and so will mitigate against CSV injection attacks.

Answer (score 8):

```
public void CreatingCsvFiles(Client client)
    {
        string filePath = "Your path of the location" + "filename.csv";
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Create(filePath).Close();
        }
        string delimiter = ",";
        string[][] output = new string[][]{
        new string[]{ "=\"" + client.phone + "\"", client.name }
        };
        int length = output.GetLength(0);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index]));
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
    }
```

Inspired from http://softwaretipz.com/c-sharp-code-to-create-a-csv-file-and-write-data-into-it/

The important part :

```
  "=\"" + client.phone + "\"", client.name
```

If the phone number is an int, of course you add .toString().

Comment: After adding this =\.when i open csv in notepad then it with show value with =Value

Answer (score 5):

Print phone number to CSV with prepended ' (single quote), so it looks like:

```
"Some Name","'0000121212"
```

Excel should treat this `0000121212` as string then.

Comment: OK, so try prepending the double quote with equal sign, like this: `"Some Name",="'0000121212"` (either with single quote inside or without). UPD: i tried without inside single quote and it worked correctly.

Comment: I had similar problems with long integers where Excel converted them to scientific format, it works when I do ="98127398217398213982173918"

Answer (score 1):

I believe converting the number into a formula like the accepted answer might not be a helpful solution for all.

The alternate solution I went with is to just add a **tab space** before the integer value.

---

*Example:*

Taking `phoneNumber` as a string variable which contains our int value

*Solution:*

`"\t" + phoneNumber`

Answer (score 0):

If you know already how much numbers **has** to be inside phone you can do like this

`phoneNumber.ToString("000000000000")`

In this example I consider that `phoneNumber` is an `int` and required length of numbers is `12`.